# When creating a text file, using richtextbox to write in it, only has one line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I make a new line, whenever there is a new line in the rich body text?
(Body is the RichTextBox)

```
    Dim a As New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\ROBLOX Enquiries\" + FileName.Text + "\Info.txt")          
    a.Write(Body.Text & vbCrLf & "Date: " + DateValue(Now))        
    a.Close()     
    MsgBox("ENQUIRY CREATED", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ENQUIRY CREATED")        
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: You mean the rtb multiline text is written as one line in file?

Comment: Yes, is there a way I can make it have the lines in the text file? @valter

Answer (score 1):

RTB using `\n` character to display new line, when windows using `\r\n` character. So you can try to replace RTB new line character with windows standard new line character to fix the problem :

```
a.Write(Body.Text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine) & vbCrLf & "Date: " + DateValue(Now))
```

Comment: Your comment was a bit confusing for me, and did not understand it clearly, but I changed the RTB to a regular textbox. Thanks anyway

Comment: new line or enter is actually a special character. To see it, put breakpoint at anyline of your code above, run application in debug mode, add `Body.Text` in visual studio watch window. There you can see all new line in RTB is actually "\n" character.